# In spark, is there a way to convert the RDD objects into case objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to the `Spark` programing and I came across a scenario where I am novice to `case class` and I need to use `case class` in my `RDD`s:

For example, I have an `RDD` of `tuples` like :

```
Array[(String,String,String)]
```

having values like:

```
Array((20254552,ATM,-5100), (20174649,ATM,5120)........)
```

Is there any method to convert the above `RDD` into:

```
20254552,trans(ATM,-5100)
```

where `trans` is a `case class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Definitely you can do that. Following code should help you do that

```
val array = Array((20254552,"ATM",-5100), (20174649,"ATM",5120))
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(array)
val transedRdd = rdd.map(x => (x._1, trans(x._2, x._3)))
```

You should create `case class` outside your current class

```
case class trans(atm : String, num: Int)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: My pleasure @JitheshGopinathan. Thanks for the upvote and acceptance. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the really the answer of your question but I recommend that you use `Dataframe`s and `Dataset`s as much as possible. Using them will benefit you a lot such as improve coding effieciency, well tested framewords with  optimizations to use less memory and benefit from spark-engine fully.

Please refer to [A Tale of Three Apache Spark APIs: RDDs, DataFrames, and Datasets](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) for more information about differences and uses case of `RDD`, `Dataframe`s and `Dataset`s

Using `Dataset`s the solution for your problem is very simple :

```
import spark.implicits._
val ds = Seq((20254552,"ATM",-5100), (20174649,"ATM",5120)).toDS()
val transsedds = ds.map(x => (x._1, trans(x._2, x._3)))
```

As @Ramesh says you should create case class outside your current class

```
case class trans(atm : String, num: Int)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My pleasure @JitheshGopinathan, thank you for upvoting my answer